# Python, match and replace list of strings with dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe column named content, which contains tweets. I have created a list of specific word combination such as

```
ls=["Apple Watch","Fitbit Device"]
```

I am struggling to write a function that will go through the each item in the list and if any of these items is found in the content tweet column, it will replace the white space in the original "Apple Watch" string with "applewatch", "Fitbit Device" with "fitbitdevice" in the dataframe column(content).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide sample dataframe

Answer (score 0):

To remove (all) white-spaces `" "` from a string, replace them by an empty string `""` using the string method `str.replace(" ", "")`, and then turn all the uppercase letters to lowercase with `str.lower()`. E.g.

```
>>> 'Apple Watch'.replace(" ", "").lower()
'applewatch'
```

For the rest, I suppose that the `content` is a list-like structure, so

```
for i in range(len(content)):
    if content[i] in ls:
        content[i] = content[i].replace(" ", "").lower()
```

(if you have a dataframe with a column "content", then use `dataframe.loc[i, "content"]` instead of the `content[i]` that I used)